# Add NSString to NSMutableArray if NSString is not already pressent - not working

Tags: nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Can't understand why this won't work, it simply says id num hasn't been used before every time... and never adds it to the array. Any help on this would be much appreciated. I'm almost certainly missing something obvious, but its driving me mad.

```
- (IBAction)idNumInputEnd:(id)sender
{
    // Check if ID Number has been used before, if it hasnt, add it to the list.
    NSString *idNumCheck = idNumberInput.text;

    if ([idNumberList containsObject:idNumCheck])
    {
        NSLog(@"This id number has been used before, ask user if he would like to reload the       data");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"This id number hasn't been used before and is thus being added to the array");
        [idNumberList addObject:idNumCheck];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your method is being called? Try to place a breakpoint inside it. Also it would be interesting to know the values of `idNumCheck` and `idNumberList`

Comment: Probably idNumberList has never been allocated+initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspect (shared by Martin, as per his comment) that `idNumberList` has never been allocated and initialized to an empty `NSMutableArray`.

If that's the case ARC will assign `nil` to `idNumberList`, therefore `[idNumberList containsObject:idNumCheck]` will evaluate to `nil`, as well as `[idNumberList addObject:idNumCheck]`

In other terms your evaluated code becomes something like

```
if (nil) {
    NSLog(@"This id number has been used before, ask user if he would like to reload the       data");
} else {
    NSLog(@"This id number hasn't been used before and is thus being added to the array");
    nil;
}
```

Given that, the `else` branch will always be taken, the `addObject` call to a `nil` object will fail silently and this causes the behavior you're experiencing.

To fix that, initialize `idNumberList` like follows:

```
idNumberList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Sorry for the very delayed response. Initialising idNumberList as you suggested worked perfectly. Thank you ver much.